# Fibres closed implies closed

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\varphi : X \to Y$ be a flat morphism between smooth affine algebraic varieties over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $Z \subset X$ be a reduced subvariety such that $Z \cap \varphi^{-1}(y)$, for $y \in Y$, are smooth connected equidimensional closed subvarieties of $X$. Is $Z$ closed in $X$? If not, is there a simple sufficient condition one could add?

Comment: In this generality, no. You must at least require that the subsets $Z \cap \varphi^{-1}(x)$ are connected. Othervise, take a curve $C \subset X$ dominating $Y$ and remove a point.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Yes, I forgot this assumption. Thank you. I'll edit.

Comment: What if $\phi$ is just identity?

Comment: @Mohan In that case, either $Z = X$ or $Z = \emptyset$ (by equidimensionality) so it works.

Comment: This is just a question of definitions but in my experience equidimensional morphisms are generally allowed to have empty fibers. In any case, its false even if you assume that $Z \cap \varphi^{-1}(y)$ is non-empty. Let $\varphi : X \to Y$ be the projection $\mathbb{A}^2_{x,y} \to \mathbb{A}^1_x$ and let $Z$ be the $x$-axis minus the origin union the point $(0,1)$. Then $Z$ is a locally closed subvariety but not closed and $Z \cap \varphi^{-1}(y)$ is a closed point of $\varphi^{-1}(y)$ for each $y \in Y$.